# A term for an action which generates a reaction it wanted to avoid

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to describe a particular kind of action to avoid a situation, but that action itself acts as a catalyst to actuate the very situation it wanted to avoid in the very first place.

Is there a generic term for such an action?

Comment: Would saying that the action *backfired* work?

Comment: No, backfiring doesn't fit unfortunately.

Comment: Why not? That'd help us find a better answer.

Comment: Well because backfiring is a reaction and I am looking a word for this entire" action-backfiring reaction" phenomenon.